# apple in app subscriptions with flutter and firebase

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, subscription

my podcast app made using flutter and firebase I already implement app in app subscriptions in my app but now the problem is when user charged automatically next month then how I get trigger and extend his expiry date in firebase

so basically I want to know how I can listen for events if apple charge any user next months